# Iterate value in javascript and form a drop down

Tags: javascript

I need to form drop down from the below value which is been passed to jsp page from back end.

**Code:**

```
   var test = ${paymentAccountForm.crdCardTyp}
     alert(test);
```

Right now I have hard code the test value.

**Alert value :**

```
[LabelValueBean[Visa,V],LabelValueBean[MasterCard,M],LabelValueBean[American Express,A],LabelValueBean[Discover,D]]
```

I need to iterate this test value to form a drop down using plan javascript.

Can I know how we can iterate this.

Comment: Can you please post actual HTML and JavaScript?  Looks like JSP or some other server template

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by _"I need to iterate this test value to form a drop down using plan javascript."_?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can somehow convert `paymentAccountForm.crdCardTyp` into a valid JSON format, you can create dropdown options dynamically like this:

```js
var labels = [{  text: 'Visa',  value: 'V'}, 
              {  text: 'MasterCard',  value: 'M'}, 
              {  text: 'American Express',  value: 'A'}, 
              {  text: 'Discover',  value: 'D'}];

var select = document.getElementById("dropdown");

for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
  var label = labels[i];
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = label.text;
  option.value = label.value;
  select.add(option);
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown"></select>
```